# Format GETDATE() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get `yy-MM`, I tried this but it doesn't work

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 'yy-MM')));
SELECT @Date AS [Date]
```

How to make it return `2020-03` rather than `2020-03-30`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in `SQL Server`. This is a job for your front end application or reporting tools

Comment: Your `'yy-MM'` is not used. Move it to the outer `Convert` and replace `date` with `varchar(10)` in there.

Comment: i want to make a `SELECT` statement with `LIKE` on it, but i want to eliminate the day

Comment: Are you actually storing dates as strings?

Comment: No i don't do that

Comment: Then how did you expect the `like` to work? You need either `where year(col) = year(@d) and month(col) = month(@d)`, or `where eomonth(col) = eomonth(@d)`, or `where col >= dateadd(d, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -2)) and col < dateadd(d, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1))`.

Comment: I already tried to Move `'yy-MM'` to outer convert and replace `date` with `VARCHAR(10)` but it is doesn't work

Comment: i'm not understand that sorry, but i just wanna put the result from this query like this `SELECT * FROM Statio_Tentative_Mstr WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), tent_effdate, 126) LIKE '2020-03%'`

Comment: That is the worst possible way to do that. If you really think that not understanding how to [do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517846/format-getdate-sql-server#comment108820941_61517846) is an excuse for doing it that way, then you would be better off storing your `tent_effdate` as `varchar(25)` to begin with.

Comment: Ok i do that now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make it return as 2020-03 rather then 2020-03-30?

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126)
```

Output

```
2020-04
```

[***Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1caafe7ff5750aac3589005523185e34)

Comment: yeah like that, but the month get minus one

Comment: This answers [the `x` part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640). The real answer though is "don't do that".

Comment: @Fragmantedbin, If you want to subtract a month then try this `SELECT convert(varchar(7),  DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()), 126) `

Comment: @GSerg, Yes. I agree. I haven't seen his comment. It was posted after i answered.

Comment: That what i was looking for, thank you @Arun Palanisamy